# WCF: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-authentication, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have set up my IIS WCF web service to use Windows authentication (over https) and on accessing the WSDL I get a request from the server to authenticate, which then works. So all is well there.

However, I cannot figure out how to pass over the current user's Windows credentials, I keep getting the error as detailed in the subject.

This is the server web.config:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>

      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="wsBindingTest">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <message negotiateServiceCredential="true" clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <protocolMapping>
        <remove scheme="http" />
        <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBindingTest" />
      </protocolMapping>

      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

This is the client:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
          <bindings>
              <wsHttpBinding>
                  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITRIMService">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
                    </security>
                  </binding>
              </wsHttpBinding>
          </bindings>
          <client>
              <endpoint address="https://servername.net/TRIMDev/TRIMService.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITRIMService"
                  contract="Service.ITRIMService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITRIMService">
                  <identity>
                      <servicePrincipalName value="host/servername.net" />
                  </identity>
              </endpoint>
          </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

This is the code that ultimately creates the channel:

```cs
ConfigurationChannelFactory<ITRIMService> channelFactory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<ITRIMService>("BasicHttpBinding_ITRIMService", config, null);
var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

I tried adding the following to the client config, with no luck, hoping it could be done without having to code anything into the client:

```xml
    <system.web>
      <identity impersonate="true"/>
      <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I just don't know enough to know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication does not work over `wsHttpBinding`, it is only supported for `NetTcpBinding`. Reference information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't think so, wsHTTPbinding is the current version and wsBasic is a legacy.

However, I have it working but I'm not entirely sure why. If I have that <identity> section it works, but if it's removed it is passing through anonymous